# Strings from two distinct arrays not matching?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, string

I'm trying to filter one array from another array. That is, I'm trying to create a third array with a logical not-intersection.

The best I can tell, it appears this block of code never matches, and `found` remains low:

```
found=0
...

if [ "$flag" = "$filtered" ]; then
    found=1
fi
```

I've tried using `==` with the same result. I also tried the `X` trick, but that did not work either (does it even apply here?): `if [ "X$flag" = "X$filtered" ]`.

I'm restricted to Bash 3. I'm using Bash because I somewhat know it. I'm restricted to 3 because the script runs on OS X, too. Because of Bash 3, I think I'm missing many useful functions, like HashMaps.

Why are the strings not matching?

---

Here is the relevant snippet. `CXXFLAGS` can be set by the user in his/her environment. I'm trying to remove flags that we explicitly test in our test script, like `-DDEBUG`, `-DNDEBUG`, and optimizations like `-O0` and `-O1`.

```
# Respect user's preferred flags, but filter the stuff we expliclty test
FILTERED_CXXFLAGS=("-DDEBUG", "-DNDEBUG", "-O0", "-O1", "-O2", "-O3", "-Os", "-Og")
# Additional CXXFLAGS we did not filter
RETAINED_CXXFLAGS=("")

if [ ! -z "CXXFLAGS" ]; then
    TEMP_CXXFLAGS=$(echo "$CXXFLAGS" | sed 's/\([[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*\)/=/g')
    IFS=' ' read -r -a TEMP_ARRAY <<< "$TEMP_CXXFLAGS"

    for flag in "${TEMP_ARRAY[@]}"
    do
        echo "Flag: $flag"
        found=0
        for filtered in "${FILTERED_CXXFLAGS[@]}"
        do
            echo "Filtered: $filtered"
            if [ "$flag" = "$filtered" ]; then
                echo "Found: $flag"
                found=1
            fi
        done
        echo "Found: $found"
        if [ "$found" -eq "0" ]; then
            echo "Retaining $flag"
            RETAINED_CXXFLAGS+=($temp)
        else
            echo "Discarding $temp"
        fi
    done
fi
```

---

Here's a trace with the `echo's` in place. The test data was simply `export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -mfpu=neon"`

```
Flag: -DNDEBUG
Filtered: -DDEBUG,
Filtered: -DNDEBUG,
Filtered: -O0,
Filtered: -O1,
Filtered: -O2,
Filtered: -O3,
Filtered: -Os,
Filtered: -Og
Found: 0
Retaining -DNDEBUG
Flag: -g2
Filtered: -DDEBUG,
Filtered: -DNDEBUG,
Filtered: -O0,
Filtered: -O1,
Filtered: -O2,
Filtered: -O3,
Filtered: -Os,
Filtered: -Og
Found: 0
Retaining -g2
Flag: -O3
Filtered: -DDEBUG,
Filtered: -DNDEBUG,
Filtered: -O0,
Filtered: -O1,
Filtered: -O2,
Filtered: -O3,
Filtered: -Os,
Filtered: -Og
Found: 0
Retaining -O3
Flag: -mfpu=neon
Filtered: -DDEBUG,
Filtered: -DNDEBUG,
Filtered: -O0,
Filtered: -O1,
Filtered: -O2,
Filtered: -O3,
Filtered: -Os,
Filtered: -Og
Found: 0
Retaining -mfpu=neon
```

Answer (score 3):

They don't match because `FILTERED_CXXFLAGS` has commas and `${TEMP_ARRAY[@]}` does not:

```
Flag: -DNDEBUG
Filtered: -DDEBUG,
Filtered: -DNDEBUG,
```

If the commas are supposed to be there, then replace:

```
if [ "$flag" = "$filtered" ]; then
```

with:

```
if [ "$flag" = "${filtered%%,}" ]; then
```

Alternatively, if the commas are not supposed to be there, then the issue is with:

```
FILTERED_CXXFLAGS=("-DDEBUG", "-DNDEBUG", "-O0", "-O1", "-O2", "-O3", "-Os", "-Og")
```

One can use `declare -p` to see what value bash has given to a variable:

```
$ declare -p FILTERED_CXXFLAGS
declare -a FILTERED_CXXFLAGS='([0]="-DDEBUG," [1]="-DNDEBUG," [2]="-O0," [3]="-O1," [4]="-O2," [5]="-O3," [6]="-Os," [7]="-Og")'
```

One can see that the commas are included in the value of each element.  While many languages *require* array elements to be separated by commas, Unix shell does not.  Instead it treats them as part of the value of the array elements.  Thus, replace the above definition with:

```
FILTERED_CXXFLAGS=("-DDEBUG" "-DNDEBUG" "-O0" "-O1" "-O2" "-O3" "-Os" "-Og")
```